# Design tableViewCell( overlaps table view cell)

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

How to design this table view cell..
Cell overlaps the another cell.
Please help me[image]

Comment: If you want to be able to get touch events on the complete images, you should implement it using UIScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

Set the y offset of the pictureImageview to be negative i.e -50.0f or so, the image will appear as starting from the cell above.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried AppleDelegate's solution but didn't work, because the top of every image is cut, maybe because it is beyond the cells bounds, even with clear color for background.

A different approach would be to believe that it's just a visual effect, and cells are not overlapping. This is possible by giving a different height for every cell with next code :

```
- (CGFloat)tableView      : (UITableView *) tableView
  heightForRowAtIndexPath : (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
// RETURN A DIFFERENT HEIGHT FOR EVERY CELL DEPENDING ON INDEXPATH,
// INCREASING IT GRADUALLY.
}
```

In the next image, the black lines look like cells' top border, but maybe that's the effect, and the real limit is the red line :

[image]

Thinking this way, only the first cell requires a special treatment for the green titles.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting constraints in storyboard and then keep the UIImageView's size/frame of image same when the image is set to UIImageView. Good Luck!